# Sow Multiple Images Selected From ELCImagePicker In a Collection view in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

i have a view controller in which i had added a collection view, when i pass array of static images its shows fine but i have to pass images to it through gallery selection or camera for this i have used ELCImagePicker in my project to select multiple images, When i select multiple images from gallery using elcimagepicker it select the images and when i hit done button on the top right of firstly it does not go back to view controller where to show images and no images are seen in a collection view. My code is,

```
  - (IBAction)select:(id)sender {

    ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] 

initImagePicker];

    elcPicker.maximumImagesCount = 4; //Set the maximum number of images to 

select, defaults to 4

    elcPicker.returnsOriginalImage = NO; //Only return the fullScreenImage, not

the fullResolutionImage
    elcPicker.returnsImage = YES; //Return UIimage if YES. If NO, only return 

asset location information

    elcPicker.onOrder = YES; //For multiple image selection, display and return 

selected order of images

    elcPicker.imagePickerDelegate = self;

    //Present modally

    [self presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];


}


- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker

 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info{

    if([info count] > 0) {

        for (NSDictionary *imageInfo in info) {

            UIImage *image = [imageInfo

valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

            NSLog(@"iii %@",image);

            _arrImages=image;

            NSLog(@"ppp %@",_arrImages);

            //do anything here

        }

    }

    [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (void)elcImagePickerControllerDidCancel:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 

numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [_arrImages count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView

 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    PatternCell *cell= [collectionView 

dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *string=[_arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"IMAGE %@",string);

    cell.img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:string];

    cell.name.text=string;

    return cell;
}

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:

(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath

 *)indexPath{

    return CGSizeMake(150.0, 150.0);}

-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:

(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:

(NSInteger)section{

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
}
```

Can any one help me where i'm making the mistake?
It only shows this screen,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xif7o.png)

Comment: can u help me in this ? @Jen Jose

Comment: "when i hit done button on the top right of firstly it does not go back to view controller where to show images and no images are seen in a collection view" which screen is shown when you close the ImagePicker screen ?

Comment: It shows my view controller in which i have place collection view to show images. @JenJose

Comment: after you dismiss the image picker, you are assigning data to  _arrImages=image; after that you need to reload the collectionview. Just add [_ collectionView reloadData];

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the selected images to collectionview.

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker

 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info{

    if([info count] > 0) {
        for (NSDictionary *imageInfo in info) {
                UIImage *image = [imageInfo    
valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

            NSLog(@"iii %@",image);

            _arrImages=image;

            NSLog(@"ppp %@",_arrImages);
               //Reload the collection view to display the selected images in cell.
           [_collectionView reloadData];
        }

    }

    [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Comment: the image picker is not dismissing how to dismiss it? @JenJose

Comment: its showing error in this line   [_collectionView reloadData]; on _collectionView. I have made outlet for it but its showing error on it yet. @JenJose

Comment: it want to replace collectionview with UICollectionView. @JenJose

Comment: i am unable to understand your issue. You please share the entire code

Comment: give me ur mail i will send u the class. @JenJose

Comment: Is it done..? sorry, I was away. email : jeneena33@gmail.com

Comment: Sorry i was away too , i had sent u the mail check it out. @JenJose

Comment: have u seen that?@JenJose

Comment: great !! happy coding :)

Comment: should i delete the answer or leave it ? did it help any how ? or you can probably delete the question

Comment: i'm confused what to say.@JenJose